# powershell script not enumerating add-member's scriptproperty input properly

Tags: powershell

My apologies if this is a dupe but after searching for some time, I wasn't able to find an answer that worked in my case.

I have a python script that searches for faces in photographs. The python script works fine and I'm now trying to incorporate its output into a csv file that I can use to run some statistics on.

Enter powershell.

Here is my powershell script:

```
$picts = gci *.jpg
$(foreach ($f in $picts) 
{
    $obj2 = New-Object System.Object       
    $obj2 | Add-Member -MemberType  NoteProperty -Name fileName -Value $f.Name
    $obj2 | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name datumN -Value { 
        python face_detect_batch.py  $f.Name 
        }
    $obj2
 }
) | export-csv t.csv
```

The python script prints a single line containing the filename it was fed along with some info about the photo.

I'm testing the script on a folder that has two jpegs in it, 1.jpg and 2.jpg. If I run the script by hand on each photo, it works as expected.

However, if I run the above script to iterate through the photos I get the following output:

```
#TYPE System.Object 
fileName    datumN

1.jpg   name: 2.jpg; blurScore: 269; facex: 68; facey: 84; faceWidth: 155; faceHeight:155
2.jpg   name: 2.jpg; blurScore: 269; facex: 68; facey: 84; faceWidth: 155; faceHeight:155
```

The output shows that the script iterates as I expect and adds the two distinct filenames to `$obj2`'s filename property but when the script property add-member executes,  my python script is fed 2.jpg both times.

I've tried feeding `[ref]$f.name` and `$global:f.name` in the value field of add-member but none of the changes make any difference - I always get 2.jpg being passed to my python script.

Why does the first reference to `$f.Name` enumerate the files as expected but the second reference only sees the last jpeg?

Comment: Try using `$this.Name` instead of `$f.Name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not use a `ScriptProperty` member to create a property whose value should be assigned *once, statically*** - instead, use a **`NoteProperty`** member:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | ForEach-Object {
  [pscustomobject] @{
    fileName = $_.Name
    datumN = python face_detect_batch.py $_.Name
  }
 } | Export-Csv t.csv
```

- Note how `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` is used to define a custom object indirectly via a hashtable literal, which simplifies its construction.
- Value `python face_detect_batch.py $_.Name` for key / property `datumN` simply invokes `python` with every input filename *at the time the object is constructed* and stores the *result* in property `datumN`, as a *one-time operation*.
- The properties of the resulting `[pscustomobject]` instance are implicitly and invariable of type `NoteProperty`, i.e., *static* values.

---

As for **what you tried**:

By creating a `ScriptProperty` member, you're assigning a *piece of code* that is run *every time the property is accessed*.

Thus, it is only later, at the time your objects are exported by `Export-Csv` that their `.datumN` property is *retrieved*, causing the script block to run *then*, at which point `$f` happens to contain the *last* iteration's value.